# OpenGL coordinates and scissor coordinates

Tags: opengl, coordinates

I want to use the scissor test, but unfortunately scissors are expressed in  pixels (int), and not in the opengl world coordinates (-1.0000 1.0000).

Can someone show me how to convert **from world coordinates** to int x y pixel way?

Answer (score 0):

Scissor test is in screen coordinates because it is a raster operation. You might convert a world coordinate to screen space by multiplying it by the MVP matrix (getting -1,1 range which you then map to pixels), but that will not allow you to clip anything else than a resulting screen space rectangle (which will be always axis aligned). Hence it doesn't make much sense to do a scissor test with world space coordinates.

Maybe tell us what is the problem you're trying to solve with the scissor test and we can find a more fitting solution.

Comment: Hello Kornel.

I want to use scissor test for GUI purpose:
drawing a window with inside things that doesn t output to the rest of the screen

The rectangle aera is well fitting for me.

I m very newbie to opengl, so concrete code would help a lot !

my application is only in -1 +1 world coordinates

thank you

Comment: For GUI it would be a lot easier to just use screen space coordinates. Precise code depends on the pipeline (fixed/shader) and if the former, the math library you're using.

Comment: Well, for screen coordonates i would prefer to stay in opengl space coordonates, to enable same proportions and places however is user screen size.I m using glew.h  GL/glu.h  glfw  glut.h  glm/glm.hpp and maths_funcs.cpp wich is coming from a book: [link]http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/

Comment: i m trying to do something like this:`code`//transfo coordonnees x y
if(x<0)
{
scissor_x=(window_sizex*(x*-1))-window_sizex;
}
else
{
scissor_x=(window_sizex*x)-window_sizex;
}

if(y<0)
{
scissor_y=(window_sizey*(y*-1))-window_sizey;
}
else
{
scissor_y=(window_sizey*y)-window_sizey;
}
`code`where x and y are float position in opengl coordinates